# ReportLab: Cannot open resource "images/logo_.jpg"

Tags: python, reportlab

I use reportlab and try to add an image but got an error.
I've read reportlab documentation and example seems easy...
I've pillow installed instead of PIL

```
    buffer = io.BytesIO()
    p = canvas.Canvas(buffer)
    p.drawImage('images/logo_.jpg', 5, 5, width=50, height=50)
```

Comment: The obvious answer is that the file doesn't exist.  What is the current working directory?

Comment: D:\Users\jl3\DevSpace\coverage\static\images ; I also try with relative path using Django {% static 'images/logo_jpg' %}

Comment: You're already in the images subdirectory, so the `drawImage()` function is looking for `images\images\logo_.jpg`.

Comment: ok, this works... p.drawImage('D:/Users/jl3/DevSpace/coverage/static/images/logo_.jpg', 5, 5, width=50, height=50) so, I only the relative path...